# How to add and save feature attribute GeoJSON with leaflet

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet, geojson

I have GeoJSON file named json_point2.
This file holds point data as follows.

```
var json_point2={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Class": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 40.193168611061743, 40.904508523555492 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Class": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 40.191358449981372, 40.902051540140285 ] } },
```

When I click this point on my web apps, I want to enter input  value of class  and save this value again.

I can click on the point with the following code and enter the attribute. But he does not record it in his database.

Mycode

```
 map.createPane('pane_point2');
map.getPane('pane_point2').style.zIndex = 602;
map.getPane('pane_point2').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
var layer_point2 = new L.geoJson(json_point2, {
    attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
    pane: 'pane_point2',
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var input = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'my-input');
        input.value = feature.properties.Class;
        L.DomEvent.addListener(input, 'change', function () {
            feature.properties.Class = input.value;
        });
        layer.bindPopup(input);
        layer_point2.toGeoJSON();
    }   
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Are you saying that the file does not update when you add the value to it? If so, that would be because you need to write the updated data to the file after you add the attribute. Otherwise it will not be there the next time you load the file.

Comment: Yes I want to add new value and update geojson file. How  can ı add new atribute value my GeoJson file and save it.

Comment: I made some changes in the code section but it did not work.

Comment: layer_point2_toGeoJSON (); did not work

Comment: I can give value with popup o web  applicaiton , but ı dint' add  this value my geojson file.